# Beginning in bat: input -> goto don't work

Tags: batch-file, set, goto

Help. This don't work after it set menuInput. It always just go to :opties. (If a type a, b,c or anything else. Who can say me what's wrong?

```
@ECHO off

:hoofdMenu
::Dit is het hoofd menu.
title Hoofdmenu
echo A. Opties
echo B. Starten van game
echo C. Stop programma
set /P menuInput="Maak een keuze:"
if %menuInput% == "a" goto opties
if %menuInput% == "b" goto spelStarten
if %menuInput% == "c" goto exit

:opties
::Geeft alle opties weer -> menu van de opties
title Opties
cls
echo Op dit momment zijn er nog geen opties mogelijk. Sorry.
pause
cls
goto :hoofdMenu

:spelStarten
::Starten van het spel
cls
title Het spel
echo Dit is nog in de maak
pause
cls
goto :hoofdMenu

:exit
::Sluit het programma
exit
```

Comment: Post your code here, please, and provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch files are less forgiving than all modern programming languagues. Here you go.

```
if %menuInput%==a goto opties
if %menuInput%==b goto spelStarten
if %menuInput%==c goto exit
```

Not really answering your question with this addition, but you should look at the `choice` command if you are running Windows Vista or newer. This command allows you to specify the allowed characters and you don't have to handle the chance that they press the wrong key. It also has some other handy features.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `"%menuInput%"=="a"` and so on to prevent errors when input is empty.