# Input -> Goto don't work -> After resolving, doesn't work

Tags: variables, batch-file, goto

[Beginning in bat: input -> goto don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143414/beginning-in-bat-input-goto-dont-work)
And I tried to get the thing work. But it doesn't seem to want to work... my script is batch as following.

```
@echo off
title [title here]
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0F
mode con cols=1000 lines=1000
[code between (nothing to do with InstallChoice]
set /p InstallChoice = -^> 
if "%InstallChoice%"=="1" goto :Install1
goto :Install
```

So...

```
if "%InstallChoice%" == 1 goto :Install1
```

doesn't work, it sends me again to :InstallChoice input, so it seem like %InstallChoice% isn't 1.

```
if "%InstallChoice%"=="1" goto :Install1
```

Unexpected goto at this time... the message I don't really get. System does not have to understand it, execute it, over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you  just have to remove extra space `set /p InstallChoice = -^>` should be `set /p InstallChoice=-^>`

Comment: Thank you, StackOverflow is awesome, and you too! Thank you very much for your help. It works. Could you please tell me how do you do this "non-seperate-lined" code block? I mean, I know how to do block with code (4 spaces) but then, I have to make a new line, how do you do that it can be in one long line?